# Batch receive with Spring AMPQ

Tags: jakarta-mail, spring-amqp

We are using `@RabbitListener` just fine to process one message after another and sending generated emails, using JavaMail to some SMTP.

Now there is request to close the connection to SMTP after specific count of messages. I have read something about `ChannelAwareMessageListener` and manual ack. This way you can acknowledge all batch messages with single ack, but I need to be able to just read some messages and then confirm only those which will be sent successfully to SMTP the others need to be dead-lettered.

Any other ideas how to close SMTP connection after count of messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a list to the unack'd delivery tags, then use `channel.basicAck(goodTag, false)` and `basicReject(badTag, false)` when you are ready.

You should only do that on the listener thread.

Comment: I need to reject and not requeue so setting `defaultRequeueRejected` to false should help right?

Comment: You said you want to control when you ack/nack - that property does not apply with the MANUAL ack mode.

Comment: I nèed to reject some to move them to dead letter queue

Comment: RIght; so my answer explains how to do that.